# Can I use sqlite in windows phone 8.1 project on VS2013?

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone, system.data.sqlite

Can I use sqlite in windows phone 8.1 project on VS2013?

I am developing some windows phone 8.1 app with the WP8.1 SDK.
https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk
But I cannot use sqlite at all.
I cannot find sqilte extension on the vs2013 extensions.
( VS2013 > TOOLS > Extensions and Updates > Online )
Is it not prepared yet?

I used sqilte very well in my W8 tablet project on vs2012.
So I think that I can use same manner.
http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/03/12/using-the-sqlite-database-engine-with-windows-phone-8-apps.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sqlite for Windows Phone 8.1 is officially released now:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d97faf6-39e3-4048-a0bc-adde2af75d1b

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use SQLite in a Windows Phone App (non SL) 8.1 project.  There isn't an official build yet for the [driver](http://sqlite.org/download.html).  More info [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/816737d8-c791-45b6-9f01-b5e39edc0176/using-sqlite-extension-in-a-windows-phone-81-universal-app?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK).  I think there will also need to be a version of the C++/CX wrapper as well, I'm not 100% sure about this though.  That lives [here](https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8).  Once the drivers are available they should show up in Visual Studio Extensions the same way they do currently for Windows Phone 8.

update:
[Using SDK/library references in Universal Windows Apps](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2014/04/17/universal-windows-apps-nuget-sdk-references-sqlite.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20timheuer%20%28Method%20~%20of%20~%20failed%20by%20Tim%20Heuer%29&utm_content=Google%20Feedfetcher)

Comment: Thank you, I'll wait sqlite official version. Until that maybe I have to use sqlCE.

Comment: @HyundongHwang http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2014/04/17/universal-windows-apps-nuget-sdk-references-sqlite.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+timheuer+%28Method+~+of+~+failed+by+Tim+Heuer%29&utm_content=Google+Feedfetcher

Comment: Thank you :) I am using that binaries from timheuer well. It works well. I am missing the standard version of sqlite WP81.

Comment: @HyundongHwang Are you sure that SQL CE works with Windows Phone 8.1 RT? I'm not talking about Silverlight 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Local Databases are suported using LINQ to SQL. sqlCE reference databases can be deployed with your app.

more information can be found below for local databases in windows phone

[Local Databses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[Reference Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I newly learn that sqlCE works well on WP8.1 and so I checked that today. But I wonder about the sqlite extention on VS2013 still.

Answer (score 0):

@Michael

I write some sample codes as you guided. 
Adding the System.Data.Linnq.dll refrence was works well and the builds well too.
But on running my app the InvalidProgramException was happend. 
I think that the WP8.0 and WP8.1 are differ each other very much.

This is exception call stack...

```
{System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
at System.Data.Linq.DataContext..ctor(String fileOrConnection)
at KakaoTalk.Tests.LocoChatLogDataContext..ctor(String connectionString)
at KakaoTalk.Tests.SqlCeTestPage.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)}
```

This is my sample codes...

```
public sealed partial class SqlCeTestPage : Page
{
    public SqlCeTestPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
    /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var dbCtx = new LocoChatLogDataContext("isostore:/locochatlog.sdf");

        if (dbCtx.DatabaseExists() == true)
        {
            dbCtx.DeleteDatabase();
        }

        dbCtx.CreateDatabase();
    }
}

public class LocoChatLogDataContext : DataContext
{
    // Pass the connection string to the base class.
    public LocoChatLogDataContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }

    // Specify a single table for the to-do items.
    public Table<LocoChatLog> Items;
}

[Table]
public class LocoChatLog : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region long logId PropertyChanged
    long _logId;
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public long logId
    {
        get
        {
            return _logId;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_logId != value)
            {
                _logId = value;
                if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    this.PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(STR_logId));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public const string STR_logId = "logId";
    #endregion

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```